# Ngrok custom hostname add cname to subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, hostname

I have `xyzfoo.com` domain. I created a DNS CNAME record which points to `ngrok.com` I have my app running locally on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` but not running remotely on `zyxfoo.com`

Does a subdomain need to be used with a custom hostname on `ngrok`? Creating a subdomain seems like a hassle through my current hosting provider, I have an extra domain laying around and I do not mind using the domain solely for testing with `ngrok`

I have a dedicated IP address and a SSL certificate. On my parent domain, `xyzfoo.com` I have also created a sub domain `foo.xyzfoo.com` through which I have also created a CNAME record for, with hostname `cname-for-ngrok` and value of `foo.xyzfoo.com`

I have two routes as I trying to get the custom hostname from ngrok to work, I am troubleshooting two ways,the `foo.xyzfoo.com` and `xyzfoo.com` are reserved domains on my ngrok dashboard. When I refresh my parent or subdomain I am not seeing my applicaiton, nor any activity on my terminal logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some DNS providers allow you to make a CNAME record instead of a A record for a apex domain (http://xyzfoo.com).  CloudFlare is one example that allows this.  These DNS providers would let you point your http://xyzfoo.com to your http://randomstuffabcd.ngrok.com.

Comment: some also allow for a low TTL so it will update more frequently if you have to restart ngrok and have it update quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Because Ngrok uses the `Host` header sent by the browser to determine how to redirect your traffic you will need to "reserve" the domain you want to use in the Ngrok dashboard. Note that doing this requires a paid Ngrok plan.

After reserving your domain you will be given a CNAME record to point it to.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pointing a free DNS CNAME (e.g. ud-jira-01.chickenkiller.com) at an ngrok hostname and when I try it out via HTTP I get back this: Tunnel ud-jira-01.chickenkiller.com not found.  I suspect ngrok is somehow noticing the host header or some other method for noticing I am trying to come in via a CNAME... and trying to break this on purpose.  Either that or I have something misconfigured!